# Cannot trigger click on href(forcing href to clicked)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have just made a script and when i tried to click href automatically when the document loads , the trigger was not occuring. I wanted that href had been automatically clicked but i got no trigger. Here is my html

```
<li style="width: 25%; max-width: 320px; max-height: 200px;">
            <a href="#" class="linkProxy"><img src="index_files/small/shirt-4.jpg" data-largeimg="index_files/large/shirt-4.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
```

And here is my Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button.linkProxy').click(function(){
    location.href = $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).attr('href');
});
});
</script>
```

Can you please help me out as i am beginner to jquery and javascript. Thanks in advance and please do suggest any other method if any.

Comment: Your url is #? Am I seeing that right?

Comment: You're also not doing anything *when the document loads* except for setting up an event handler.

Comment: **I believe you need to spell out what you want to do exactly.** Triggering a click event on the `a` element does nothing at all as it does not have a `rel` attribute.

Comment: This question is not clear, it can mean 1 of 2 things. You either want to handle a button click/href click, or you actually want it to redirect on page load. You have 2 answers which satisfy both situations. Do you think you could clean up your question some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('button.linkProxy')
```

will search for `<button>` elements with class `linkProxy` and
 will not match any elements since there are no `<button>` in your html.

You need to target `<a>` tags with class `linkProxy` as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a.linkProxy').click(function(){
  location.href = $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).attr('href');
 });
 $('a.linkProxy').trigger('click');
});
```

*Also note that there's no `rel` attribute in your `html`, idk what you're trying to do with it since you haven't explained it in question...*

Comment: I just tried your code and it's working fine and i found that the location is undefined in your code so it is redirected to something like /undefined

Comment: You're using `$(this).attr('rel')` which will try to access the attribute `rel` of the clicked `<a>` tag, while there's no such attribute... can you update the question with what you're trying to do..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a redirect. An "Automatic click" would be that.

You can try one of the following two to simulate an "automatic click" when the page loads.

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button.linkProxy').click(function(){
location.href = $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).attr('href');
});
$('button.linkProxy').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

You have just defined in your code how to interpret the click event, you didn't actually made the "click".